# Can an InnoDB page contain data from different indexes?

Tags: index, innodb, data-pages, page-splits

(In this question, I assume that the data of a table is acťually an index (`PRIMARY`), so I don't differentiate between table data and column indexes)

I've compacted an "old" InnoDB table (via null ALTER TABLE), and observed the space taken by the indexes, before and after, via the `mysql.innodb_index_stats` table.

The size decreased (for some indexes, significantly); this lead to a question: can a single InnoDB page contain data from different indexes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No a page can only hold records from a single index.
see: [innodb page header docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/innodb-page-header.html)
long story short - you have a field PAGE_INDEX_ID which is an identifier of the index the page belongs to.

Regards,
Jony